# FactoryGirl email already exist when create(:user)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, factory-bot

I am using FactoryGirl in my test, but when I do @user = create(:user), I get

```
ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Validation failed: Email has already been taken
```

I already setup sequence in my factories like this

```
       FactoryGirl.define do
          sequence :email do |n|
            "email#{n}#{rand(200).to_s}#{rand(200).to_s}@factory.com"
          end

          factory :user do
            email
            password  'password'
            password_confirmation  'password'
            customer_id   nil
            staff
          end
        end
```

Comment: I would try to wrap `email` to block `{ email }`. PS I can't check it now myself

Comment: Try `email :factory => :email`

Comment: In FactoryBot i'm using  [  association :follower, factory: :user ]